# Can an IDEA plugin read exception messages from the console, and write to the console?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm interested in creating an IDEA plugin out of interest and course requirements, but this seems like a niche area. There's not a lot materials to learn from online apart from the official documents. So I want to to know if something like what I described in the title is feasible?
The idea is to write an IDEA plugin that detects certain exception messages from the console when they occur, get the corresponding augmentation from an existing source, and print the augmentation messages in addition to the original stack trace.

Comment: you should better look for something that detects Exceptions when they're thrown, makes a lot more sense

Comment: or analyze logs and convert them (instead of stack traces)

Comment: I didn't make it clear before, the idea is to enhance the stack trace messages as they occur, and has to be in the form of an IDEA plugin

Comment: that "idea" makes no sense. The stack traces are the way they are to deliver the information needed to understand and resolve the issue. why would you want to try and alter those?

Comment: IntelliJ Plugin Marketplace has many plugins labeled with "console". You may find an open source plugin to start with. Your plugin would really save StackOverflow from the questions like "My app crashes NPE", "got NumberFormatException", "I know better than the compiler" ...

Comment: @ocos Thanks! When I first learned coding I struggled with those error messages as a beginner. The plugin might not be helpful at all to experienced developers but could be somewhat helpful to complete beginners.

Comment: Some crash reporting dashboards explain well-known exceptions like `Android SDK .. someMethod() implementation is buggy ... is the cause of the crash X.` It might be helpful for everybody.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.